# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot' has no index signature

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

I'm creating with Angular2 simply routing, i want to pass from object property name to url and everything works, my links are dynamicly generated but after few seconds i get that error:

[image]

my routerLink code:

```
      <a [routerLink]="['category/', electronic.name]" *ngFor="let electronic of electronics ">
        {{electronic.name}}
      </a>
```

my component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DatabaseService } from "../../service/database.service";
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category-list',
  templateUrl: './category-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category-list.component.css']
})
export class CategoryListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private database: DatabaseService, private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let name = this.activeRoute.snapshot['name'];
    console.log(name);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler is complaining about the following line

```
let name = this.activeRoute.snapshot['name'];
```

This is because if you look at the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot), it does not have an indexer on the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` interface to retrieve info like you are attempting. An indexer would look like this:

```
interface Example {
    [key:string]: any;
}
```

You'll want to take a look at the documentation to see what is the proper way to use that object.